# No such file or directory error in Webpack + highlight module

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron, highlight

I'm working on an Electron app which requires the code highlighting feature. I installed [highlight module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highlight) as a node dependency and use **webpack** to bundle all the code into the *app.bundle.js*.

However, when I launch the Electron app, I notice an error from the highlight module complaining

```
Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '//vendor/highlight.js/languages/'
```

Inside *app.bundle.js*, the highlight module still uses the `vendor/highlight.js/languages/` to search for its utilities files which I thought should be included into *app.bundle.js* with their paths updated.

```
var Highlight = module.exports
        , fs = __webpack_require__(336)
        , hljs = __webpack_require__(408).hljs
        , langRelPath = "vendor/highlight.js/languages/"
        , langPath = __dirname + "/" + langRelPath
        , reEndsWithJs = /\.js$/i
        , loadedMap = {}
        , availableMap = {}
        ;
```

It's my first time to use webpack, so it might be caused by some webpack misconfigurations. I paste the *webpack.config.js* for your convenience.

```
'use strict'

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './app/app.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
          test: /\.js$/,
          include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')],
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loaders: ['babel?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=react']
        }, {
          test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
          loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
        }, {
            test: /\.json/,
            loader: 'json'
        }, {
          test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
          loader: 'url-loader'
        }, {
          test: /\.html$/,
          loader: 'html'
        }, {
          test: /\.txt$/,
          loader: 'text'
        }]
    },
    target: 'electron'
};
```

Does anyone have some idea for this?

（Everything works fine when not bundle by webpack.）

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Can you include your package.json and also the parts of your code where you're importing and using `highlight`?